# Alternative to zero size struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So I am trying to find an alternative to what I am doing here because it is illegal to use zero sized arrays in a struct. What code could accomplish nearly the same task?

You can see what I am basically trying to do here is create a struct for an animated object with four sides.

```
struct Sprite
{
  double x;
  double y;
  int textureFront[];
  int textureBack[];
  int textureRight[];
  int textureLeft[];
};

int boxAnimation[7] = {10,5,6,2,76,8,4};

Sprite sprite[8] =
{
  {20.5, 11.5, {10}},
  {18.5, 4.5, boxAnimation},
  {10.0, 4.5, {10}},
  {10.0, 12.5, {10}},
  {3.5, 6.5, {10}},
  {3.5, 20.5, {10}},
  {3.5, 14.5, {10}},
  {14.5, 20.5, {10}},
};
```

Only textureFront is assigned in these just for example.

Comment: So what you want is a pointer?

Comment: Just use a `std::array` if you have a specific size and `std::vector` otherwise.

Comment: @kfsone, I don't know about you, but if I was the user of the class, I'd appreciate not having to manual manage memory for each one of those.

Comment: You wouldn't, he's using static assignment which translates to int* textureFront = {10}; You'd need to mark it constant, but your suggestion is much better because he's going to want to know the size.

Comment: I thought about using a pointer, but I don't understand how can I initialize it in the same way. When I change it to int *textureFront; then I can't initialize it like Sprite sprite[8] = {...};

Answer (score 0):

Try writing an constructor which will take the three argument you are passing and then internally make the other three remaining fields null or any other logic you want to have.